# What is the difference in defining a variable in .h file's interface() method alone without synthesis it?

Tags: objective-c, header, scope, getter-setter, synthesis

I define a variable in .h file's interface method like this...

```
@interface ......{
int a;
}
```

Then i use it in .m file, it works fine....

Also i modified the code as

```
@interface ......{
int a;
}
@property(nonatomic) int a;
```

in .h file, and in .m file i set the int value as

```
@synthesis a;
```

Now also it works fine...

What is the different between both cases?

Thank you